# Delete all docker instances at once

Tags: bash, docker, shell, command

I'm new to dockers and other concepts. I've lots of unused dockers running and I would want to remove all of them. Now I'm manually killing it. Can we do it at once?

Comment: Yes you can do. But why you use python?

Comment: Sorry, I've removed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Emon mentioned you can either go for docker prune. But keep in mind that pruning the system will remove any stopped containers and all **unused images.**
Since you've tagged shell, I'm adding this shell script also.

```
echo -e "******* Start *******"
echo -e "\n=====> Stopping & Cleaning up UNUSED containers.."
for i in `docker ps -a | grep -v CONTAINER | awk '{print $1}'`; do docker stop $i ; docker rm $i ; done

echo -e "[CLEARED]\n"
docker ps -a

echo -e "\n=====> Removing UNUSED container images.."

for i in `docker images | grep none | awk '{print $3}'`; do docker rmi $i ; done
echo -e "[CLEARED]\n"
docker images
```

This script can be changed accordingly to your need like if you want to remove only containers or even images also.

This can further also be done easily by

`docker ps -a | grep "pattern" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm`

If you want to remove only the exitted containers alone, you can use it

```
`docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -q)`
```

Comment: There is no need to grep into awk. Awk can do the grepping for you.

Answer (score 3):

- `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

> This command deletes all stopped containers. The command `docker ps -a -q` above returns all existing container IDs and passes them to the `docker rm` command which deletes them. Running containers are not deleted.

OR, try this one.

- `docker system prune -a`

> Remove all unused images not just dangling ones. also it will remove all build cache